# Effect size derived from LME longitudinal model: the statistical findings projected back down onto a group of people

Tags: r, mixed-model, regression-coefficients, effect-size, regression-strategies

I have been studying the change in a metric X with a linear mixed effect model. I have built this model in a multivariate setting, so I can see  how each of my covariates (Time, sex, age) affect X. Subsequently, I assessed how the time-differences were impacted by sex and age using simple interaction models.

I paste here my code and results here:

`mod1.lme <- lme(X ~ Time + bmi+ sex+ smoker + drinker + diabetes + hypertension + race , random = ~ 1|ID, data = df1, na.action = na.omit, method = "ML")`

`summary(mod1.lme)`

[image]

`mod3.lme <- lme(X ~  Time + sex + Time * sex , random = ~ 1|ID, data = df1, na.action = na.omit, method = "ML")`

`summary(mod3.lme)`

[image]

Then I have substracted the mean to the metric BMI, because I was told this would eliminate the regression to the mean for this metric

`df1$bmi_acc = df1$bmi-df1$mean_bmi`

and assessed its longitudinal impact like this (maybe I should have done it with an interaction model?)

[image]

**THE IMPORTANT QUESTION IN THIS POST**:

From these results I could say that there is change over time in the metric X (based on mod1), and that there are several variables affecting this the variable X crossectionally, but after testing them all in interaction models, I see that only sex (women(==0) progress more than men(==1)) and people with high BMI have a higher progression over time.

**EFFECT SIZE:** For example, given these results, I would like to know if I can say (based on my cofficients) that for example women with high BMI would progress at *xy*% per year, while a an average men with BMI *xy*, and a starting X of *xy*, would progress at *xy*% per year.

The way I normally interpret these coefficients is: (based on mod1) For every year, you will increase 1.72 in X (so 581.48 + 1.72). The other covariates in that model are crossectional and I am not sure how to interpret them in this context.

I am confused though as to how to include the interaction models in this context.
Shall I forget about mod1 and focus on the specific interaction models?

**My interpretation:**

> SEX: Based on model 3:

For every increase in a year, you will suffer an increase of 2.76 in X, that if you are a woman, will be 1.78 in addition to men. So the final model will be:

- Women: 687.23 + 2.76 +1.78 = 691.77 (being a woman you would expect an increase in X of 0.66% per year)
- Men: 687.23 + 2.76 = 689.99 (being a man you would expect an increase in X of 0.40% per year)

> For BMI (based on model 2)

where every increase in a BMI unit would increase X by 3.79...

Going from a BMI of 25 to 31 Kg/m2 in one year would mean:

6*3.79= 22.7
697.89 +22.7 = 720.59 (an increase of 3.25%)

if we merge this with the previous context. We would say:

- Women: 0.66% + 3.25% = 3.91%
- Men: 0.40% + 3.25% = 3.65%

**Is this all right??** I am trying to make my results easy to read for clinicians.

Thanks!!

Comment: How is time treated in your data/model? As a factor or numeric variable?

Comment: hi Erik, time is a continuous variable: everyone has a 0 in visit 1 (timepoint 0) and the variable is measured in years so at visit 2 they might have a time from 1 to 2 years (correspondent to time in years to visit 2 from visit 1)

Comment: I see. Is there a reason you are not treating the Time slope as random? That would be equivalent to a growth curve model.

Comment: Is there some reason why you are formulating this as a set of separate models? Usually it's best to put all predictors (and interactions) of interest into a single model.

Comment: @ErikRuzek, The reason is because I wanted to see if time was significant for X, I thought to use it as fixed and nested random - lme(X ~ Time + bmi+ sex+ smoker + drinker + diabetes + hypertension + race ,random = ~ 1|ID/Visit (...).  I think this would be more accurate? (being Visit a factorial variable 1 and 2)

Comment: @EdM I was told by an stats professor that is better to study your model on one side and the interactions separately to avoid overfitting (I think this was the reason, now I am doubting)

Comment: I think you should minimally include a random slope for time and once you have that, run your interactions. See https://quantdev.ssri.psu.edu/tutorials/growth-modeling-basics

Comment: Thank you Erik. I guess this would address a complete different thing, right? but I do agree with you that (random = ~ 1|ID/Visit should be there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this scale of a data set, you should be combining all your predictors into a single model. Doing multiple mini-models runs a risk of omitted-variable bias, not allowing you to take the omitted predictors into account in each mini-model.

The best approach is explained for example in [Harrell's course notes](http://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf), in particular Chapter 4 on multivariable modeling strategies. Consider how much data you have, decide on how many predictors that might allow you to evaluate, and build a rich model that captures as much of the data as is reasonable without overfitting.

You have on the order of 5000 observations total, with a bit under 2 observations per individual on the average. With your continuous outcome you could probably accommodate 100 or more predictors, counting each interaction term as a predictor. It seems that you could easily incorporate all potential 2-way fixed-effect interactions into your model, with a random intercept accounting for (estimated) baseline differences among individuals. Why not do so, at least to start? If you want a simpler model that is "easier to read for clinicians" you can always pull back from that, trading off the loss of predictive ability against the parsimony you achieve.

In terms of centering continuous variables like `BMI`, that will make interpretation of the intercept and the coefficients of predictors with which it interacts easier to interpret, but it won't affect any predictions from your model.

In terms of interpreting your model, you are predicting *individual* values of `X` as a function of all of your predictors, including `Time`. So you need to evaluate interactions to see whether there are combined effects of individual predictors that are different from what you would expect from each predictor individually. That's not only true for things like `Time` and `sex` as in one of your mini-models to see if the effect of `Time` on outcome depends `sex`, but also for `BMI` and `sex` if you think that the association of `BMI` with outcome depends on `sex`, and so on.

With the default treatment coding used in R, the interpretation of coefficients and interaction terms is straightforward if tedious. The intercept is the estimated value when all continuous predictors have values of 0 and all categorical predictors are at their baseline levels. The individual coefficient for a predictor involved in interactions is its *extra* association with outcome *when all its interacting predictors are at 0 or reference values*. Two-way interaction coefficients represent the *differences* in outcome between what you would predict from the individual coefficients and what you get with both together.

*In response to comment:*

The principles in the previous paragraph can be applied to your model `mod3.lme`. With `female` as the reference condition (`sex = 0`), then we can say the following:

The intercept of $687.2$ is the estimated outcome for a female at `Time =0`.

For a female, the outcome increases by $2.77$ per unit of `Time`, the coefficient for `Time`. (I think you might have misinterpreted the `Time` coefficient; it's for the reference "female" condition of the interacting `sex` predictor, while you seem to have taken it to be the coefficient for "male.")

For a male at `Time = 0`, the estimated outcome is $687.2 + 17.3 = 704.5$ (intercept plus coefficient for `sex = 1`). (Men start at that level at `Time = 0`, not at $687.2$ as you seem to imply in part of the question.)

For a male, the estimated outcome increases by $2.77-1.78=0.99$ per unit time, the `Time` coefficient plus the `Time:sex` interaction. (You were correct that the change per unit time is $1.78$ greater for females than males according to the interaction term, but see above for the misinterpretation of the `Time` coefficient itself.)

You apply the same interpretations to *all* predictors involved in interactions. I find it's best to think things through one coefficient at a time, asking just what that coefficient represents and the corresponding value(s) of the predictor(s) by which to multiply the coefficient, then adding all the terms up. That's tedious, but it's the best way I know to avoid errors. Or you can use software designed to make such estimates easier. Many find the [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans) in R to be a help.

Comment: thank you  for this very comprehensive explanation. I have 3 question: 1) could you give me an example of a 2-way-fixed-effect interaction based on my variables? 2) would the bit "my interpretation" be correct based (I know the model is not correct, but if it were) and 3) The variables that are not time  in model 1 contribute to a crossectional change, how would you add those coeffcients? - I am confused on the interpretation (I know the intercept is the value when all is 0 etc but I am wondering how to sum up the coefficients when you have crossectional and longitudinal info together.

Comment: @Lili I edited the question to address most of your comment. A predictor whose value changes over time for an individual in your data will be modeled according to its value at the particular `Time`. For making predictions from the model, if you want to allow for a change in a predictor value over time, just set up the predictor values at each time to be what you wish, get separate predictions for each time with the corresponding set of predictor values, then take the difference.

Comment: this is awesome! Very useful as always (this is not the first time I use one of your answers) - thank you! :)

Comment: one last question: how would you interpret an interaction of 2 continuous variables (for example Time:bmi) ?

Comment: @Lili Ian an interaction between continuous predictors can be thought of like this:  how much does a one-unit change in Time _alter_ the response to a one-unit change in BMI? (And vice-versa.)